# .py compiled .exe wont run on a certain server, error posted

Tags: python, exception, runtime

I wrote a health monitoring app for a couple servers of mine(win servers 2016) and it works fine on one , but crashes on launch on the other server with the following error:

I never got any of this as warnings or errors in the IDE or code itself

thank you

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\PI Connector Health Monitor>PIConnectorHealth.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PIConnectorHealth.py", line 23, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "clr.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "pythonnet\__init__.py", line 115, in load
  File "clr_loader\wrappers.py", line 20, in __call__
RuntimeError: cannot call null pointer pointer from cdata 'int(*)(void *, int)'
[4320] Failed to execute script 'PIConnectorHealth' due to unhandled exception!
```

Comment: what is 'PIConnectorHealth' ?  it seem that there is code missing:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: PIConnectorHealth is the original script

Comment: would need to see relevant lines of code...  there error message tells you where the error might be.

Comment: Resolved. I found it was a set of DLL assembles that needed to be included and pointed to as part of another program "AFSDK assemblies" I rebuilt the .exe and included an installer dir with the assemblies, then point to those in the script and deployed with INNO setup engine. thank you.